# cannot connect client to server in java

Tags: java, client, server

I am still a newbie and all and I am sure that this has been asked many times already.
I have created a client server tool in java and its running perfectly fine when I run it on the same machine.
But when I try to run the client on a different machine but on the same network it doesnt connect to the server.
So could someone tell me what I can try/do to rectify it.

Thanks.

code snippet from client :

```
serverIP = String.valueOf(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
int Port = 5000;

.
.
.
try 
            {
                sock = new Socket(serverIP, Port);
                InputStreamReader streamreader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(streamreader);
                writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                writer.println(username +":"+ encPassword+":has connected"+":Connect"); // Displays to everyone that user connected.
                writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
                isConnected = true; // Used to see if the client is connected.
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                chatTextArea.append("Cannot Connect! Try Again. \n");
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                usernameField.setEditable(true);
                pass.setEditable(true);
            }
        ListenThread();
.
.
.

public void ListenThread() 
{
     Thread IncomingReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
     IncomingReader.start();
}
```

code snippet from server :

```
public void run() 
    {
        clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
        onlineUsers = new ArrayList();  
        try 
        {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (true) 
            {
                // set up the server writer function and then begin at the same
                // the listener using the Runnable and Thread
                Socket clientSock = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
                // use a Runnable to start a 'second main method that will run
                // the listener
                Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSock, writer));
                listener.start();
                outputPane.append("Got a connection. \n");
    } // end while
        } // end try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            outputPane.append("Error making a connection. \n");
        } // end catch
}
```

Comment: 'it doesnt connect to the server' usually means you should get an exception which should give you a rough idea why it can't connect.

Comment: I get connection refused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the client still tries to connect to the machine it's running on :

```
serverIP = String.valueOf(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
```

`serverIP` should get the value of the remote machine (preferably using some configuration) ..

Comment: @AkshayAgarwal Try serverIP = 'The ip of the server you are trying to connect to'

Comment: The client machine needs the server machine address (ip).
That address needs to be assigned to the 'serverIp' variable.

You can get the network details in the server machine using ipconfig (windows) \ ifconfig (unix\linux) command.

Comment: what if the server ip keeps changing ? is there any dynamic way to get the server ip and use it instead of hard-coding the serving ip beforehand.

Comment: You can deploy your server code to some free hosting solutions that provide you with a temporary domain (like heroku or google).

When your app is production ready and in a large scale you'd most likely want to connect to a load balancer.

Comment: so in all in the end I will have to provide it with a hard-coded ip of the server. Thanks guys for the quick and informative inputs and suggestions. I guess I can finally get it to work.